# Hash Join vs Hash Semi Join

Tags: postgresql, join, hashing

PostgreSQL 9.2

I'm trying to understand the difference between `Hash Semi Join` and just `Hash Join`.

Here're two queries:

***I***

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerid IN (SELECT
customerid FROM customers WHERE state='MD');

Hash Semi Join  (cost=740.34..994.61 rows=249 width=30) (actual time=2.684..4.520 rows=120 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (orders.customerid = customers.customerid)
  ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..220.00 rows=12000 width=30) (actual time=0.004..0.743 rows=12000 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=738.00..738.00 rows=187 width=4) (actual time=2.664..2.664 rows=187 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 7kB
        ->  Seq Scan on customers  (cost=0.00..738.00 rows=187 width=4) (actual time=0.018..2.638 rows=187 loops=1)
              Filter: ((state)::text = 'MD'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 19813
```

***II***

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM orders o JOIN customers c ON o.customerid = c.customerid WHERE c.state = 'MD'

Hash Join  (cost=740.34..1006.46 rows=112 width=298) (actual time=2.831..4.762 rows=120 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (o.customerid = c.customerid)
  ->  Seq Scan on orders o  (cost=0.00..220.00 rows=12000 width=30) (actual time=0.004..0.768 rows=12000 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=738.00..738.00 rows=187 width=268) (actual time=2.807..2.807 rows=187 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 37kB
        ->  Seq Scan on customers c  (cost=0.00..738.00 rows=187 width=268) (actual time=0.018..2.777 rows=187 loops=1)
              Filter: ((state)::text = 'MD'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 19813
```

As can be seen, the only difference in the plans is that in the first case, the hastable consumes `7kB`, but in the second `37kB` and that the node is `Hash Semi Join`.

But I don't understand the difference in the hashtable size. The `Hash` node uses perfectly the same `Seq Scan` node having the same `Filter`. Why is there the difference?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual output of the queries?  Or, use `explain (analyze, verbose)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first query, only the customer_id needs to be saved from the `customers` into the hash table, because that is the only data needed to implement the semi-join.

In the second query, all of the columns need to be stored into the hash table, because you are selecting all of the columns from the table (using `*`) rather than just testing for existence of the customer_id.